# Will upgrading cucumber from 1.1.8 to 1.2.5 improve performance of my test suite?

Tags: java, cucumber, automated-tests

We have a substantial cucumber test suite implemented in java. Currently we have cucumber 1.1.8 running, am I likely to see any performance improvement by  upgrading to 1.2.5?

Thanks,
Ollie

Comment: How about going through the [changelog](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/History.md) of these versions between 1.1.8 and 1.2.5 ?

Comment: I did, and dont see any reference to performance improvement...I was hoping someone may have performed a similar jump in core versions and saw improvements! Thanks tho...